In the deployment environment revalidation request does not work in ‘/’ page
There is a component on the ‘/’ path that displays products, and the request is sent as follows:
const getRecentProducts = async () => {
  try {
    const baseUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL;
    const res = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/api/products/recent`, {
      next: { tags: ['products'], revalidate: 10 },
    });
    if (!res.ok) {
      console.error('API request failed:', res.status, res.statusText);
      throw new Error('Failed to fetch products');
    }
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log('HELLO = ', data);
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error occurred while executing getRecentProducts function:', error);
    throw error;
  }
};

export default getRecentProducts;

Additionally, on the ‘/sell’ page, the API makes the following revalidation requests:
export async function POST(req) {
    revalidateTag('products');
    revalidatePath('/');
    revalidatePath('/shop');
    revalidatePath(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}/`);
    revalidatePath(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}/shop`);
}

At first, I tried only revalidateTag('products'); but the revalidation request did not work. Then I added revalidatePath('/'); and revalidatePath('/shop');, and when that didn’t work, I added revalidatePath(${process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL}/); and revalidatePath(${process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL}/shop);.
Despite these attempts, the ‘/’ page data remains the same as it was during the build. The revalidate: 10 revalidation option also does not work.
Even router.refresh() is not working on the ‘/’ page, while it works fine on other pages.
However, everything works fine in the local development environment. In the deployment environment using
next run build and next run start
revalidation does not occur no matter what.
Additionally, we are using React Query, but even with staleTime = 0, it always fetches the previous data in CSR. This issue also occurs only on the ‘/’ page.
Provide environment information
Operating System:
  Platform: darwin
  Arch: arm64
  Version: Darwin Kernel Version 23.6.0: Fri Jul  5 17:56:41 PDT 2024; root:xnu-10063.141.1~2/RELEASE_ARM64_T6000
  Available memory (MB): 16384
  Available CPU cores: 10
Binaries:
  Node: 22.3.0
  npm: 10.8.1
  Yarn: 1.22.19
  pnpm: 8.14.0
Relevant Packages:
  next: 14.2.5 // Latest available version is detected (14.2.5).
  eslint-config-next: 14.2.3
  react: 18.3.1
  react-dom: 18.3.1
  typescript: 5.4.5
Next.js Config:
  output: N/A

Main Page Revalidation Request Not Working
Expected Behavior:
When the function
revalidateTag('products'); is executed, all requests using the ‘products’ tag should be revalidated.
